# Which Redis data structure would you recommend me?

Tags: database, redis, nosql

I'm trying to decide which data structure should I use for a particular project on Redis. We're supposed to create a data base that's able to store metadata about calls, emails and Whatsapp messages (i.e date, time) and then find out, for example, *every call a specific person made on May 14th*

The problem is that I'm pretty new to Redis so I was trying to store the data about a person, the calls, the emails and the whatsapp messages on hashes like so:
`hmset person:1 name John phone_n 001 email "a@a" wpacc 100`, `hmset call:1 date "5/14..."`, `hmset email:1 origacc "a@a"...` and so on. But I came to realize that this method wouldn't help me when querying for the data I need.

Guess I'm supposed to use sets or sorted sets, but I don't know how to use them for my purposes: should I store the data about a call like: `sadd calls:originnum 001`, `sadd calls:destnum 002`? But then, how would I be able to correlate that origin phone number with the date it called the destination phone number?

If you could point me in the right direction it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Can you share queries you are expecting to make on such dataset?

Comment: Hi, sure. Here's a few examples:

- The calls a specific person made on a specific date
- Find out if a specific person called another specific person
- Return the messages a specific person sento to another specific person
- Every person that was called on a specific date
- Every person who called someone on a specific date

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using core Redis you are on the good path using:

- HASHES to store the core data
- SET/SORTED SETS to store some kind of indexing.

This will ask you to code the logic to query the data and keep the index up to date.

**SIMPLIFY THIS WITH MODULES**

That said, using [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io/) or [RediSearch](http://redisearch.io/) modules you can simply this.

I won't do it too many details here, as I have explained how you can do queries on values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338227/redis-update-sorted-set-on-key-expire/64341299#64341299). (if this is not clear enough let me know, and I will add a more detail response here if you think it is needed)

Take a look to this [RediSearch Tutorial](https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-getting-started) to see how you can easily achieve your need using this module.